# Using json data how to create form in sencha

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to read json data from file - content of the json file shown below

```
    {
    "form": {
        "fields" : [
                {
                    "field":"textfield",
                    "name": "username",
                    "constrain": "5-10",
                    "value": ""
                },
                { 
                    "field":"textfield",
                    "name": "password",
                    "constrain": "5-10",
                    "value": ""
                },
                { 
                    "field":"datepickerfield",
                    "name": "Birthday",
                    "constrain": "5-10",
                    "value": "new Date()"
                },
                { 
                    "field":"selectfield",
                    "name": "Select one",
                     "options":[
                        {"text": "First Option",  "value": 'first'},
                        {"text": "Second Option", "value": 'second'},
                        {"text": "Third Option",  "value": 'third'}
                        ]
                },

            ]    
      }
}
```

**Model**

```
    Ext.define('dynamicForm.model.Form', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: [
                {name: 'field', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'constrain', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
             ],
             hasMany: {model: 'dynamicForm.model.SelectOption', name: 'options'}
        }
    });

Ext.define('dynamicForm.model.SelectOption', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'text', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
         ]
    }
});
```

**store**

```
Ext.define('dynamicForm.store.FormStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'formStore',
    config : {
        model : 'dynamicForm.model.Form',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'form.json',

            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                rootProperty : 'form.fields'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

This what i tried so for.

```
    var fromval = Ext.create('dynamicForm.store.FormStore');
    fromval.load(function (){
        console.log(fromval);
              // i added register view which having form panel with id "testForm"
            Ext.Viewport.add({
                xtype : 'register'
            });
        for(i=0; i< fromval.getCount(); i++) {
            console.log("------");
            Ext.getCmp('testForm').add({
                    xtype: fromval.getAt(i).data.field,
                    label: fromval.getAt(i).data.name,
                    value: fromval.getAt(i).data.value,
                    options: [
                        {text: "First Option",  value: "first"},
                        {text: "Second Option", value: "second"},
                        {text: "Third Option",  value: "third"}
                    ]
            });
        }
    });
```

two text fileds and date are woking good, but i don't know how to get options for select field from store, just heard coded now.

over all Based on the above json data, i need to create sencha form dynamically.

Comment: @TDeBailleul i can't find any post related to my question in that website.

Comment: No there is nothing related to your question. But have you read the article ? From the article: "If you’re a developer and you’re about to ask another developer a technical question (on a forum, via email, on a chat channel, or in person), you’d better be ready to answer the question “What have you tried?” [...] The problem is that this person’s problem-solving technique is to ask for the solution. Not to seek advice on how to approach the task but to just ask for the code, fully formed and ready to go"

Comment: @TDeBailleul i never look for ready code in stack overflow, i just want an idea and i am trying

Comment: Ok then, do you have access to the JSON ? Can you modify it before it is sent/retrieved ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul, i updated what i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to follow MVC structure:

Create a model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.FormModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: ["field","name"]
}
});
```

A store with proxy:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.FormStore',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 
config:
{
    model: 'MyApp.model.FormModel',
    autoLoad:true,
    proxy:
    {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'FormData.json', //Your file containing json data
        reader:
        {
                rootProperty:'form.fields'
        }
    }
}
});
```

The formData.json file:

```
{
"form": {
    "fields" : [
            {
                "field":"textfield",
                "name": "username"
            },
            { 
                "field":"textfield",
                "name": "password"
            },
        ]    
  }
}
```

And then use the **FormStore** to fill the form data as you need.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginPage', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
config: {
items:{
xtype:'fieldset',
layout:'vbox',
items:[{
        flex:1,
        xtype:'textfield',
        id:'namefield',
        placeHolder:'Username'
    },{
        flex:1,
        xtype:'passwordfield',
        id:'passwordfield',
        placeHolder:'Password'
    }]
},
listeners:{
    painted:function()
    {
        var store=Ext.getStore('FormStore');
        while(!store.isLoaded())
        {
            console.log("loading...");
        }

        var record=store.getAt(0);
        Ext.getCmp('namefield').setValue(record.data.name);
        Ext.getCmp('passwordfield').setValue(record.data.password);
    }
}
}
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @Malay Shah, i did exactly same and i can get the fields value from store, now i am trying to add field dynamically to from panel which is already created and i am not successful yet.

Comment: This might help, though little out of track.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616286/recursive-parsing-of-json-object-to-construct-html-elements

specifically, you could have **options** property as empty {} in first 3 items.

Comment: how to get options property from form model

Comment: `var opt= formval.getAt(i).raw.options;
       if(opt)
       {
        console.log(opt);
       }`

It logs, couldn't figure out a proper way yet though.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "xtype":"textfield",
            "title":"UserName",
            "name": "username"
        },
        { 
            "xtype":"textfield",
            "title":"password",
            "name": "password"
        },
        { 
            "xtype":"textfield",
            "title":"phone no",
            "name": "birthday"
        },
        { 
            "xtype":"textarea",
            "title":"address",
            "name": "address"
        }
    ]
}

Ext.define('dynamicForm.model.FormModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        fields: ['field', 'name']
    });


Ext.define('dynamicForm.store.FormStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'dynamicForm.model.FormModel',
    proxy : 
    {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'data/user.json',

        reader : 
        {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty:'data'
        },

        autoLoad: true
    }
});


Ext.define('dynamicForm.view.DynaForm',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias:'widget.df1',

    items:[]

});

Ext.application({
    name:'dynamicForm',
    appFolder:'app',

    controllers:['Users'],

    launch:function(){
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{

            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'df1',

                    items:[]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});

Ext.define('dynamicForm.controller.Users',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',

    views:['DynaForm'],
    models:['FormModel'],
    stores:['FormStore'],

    refs:[
    {
        ref:'form1',
        selector:'df1'
    }
    ],

    init:function(){
        console.log('in init');
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            }
        });
    },

    onPanelRendered: function() {

        var fromval=this.getFormStoreStore();
        var form=this.getForm1();
        fromval.load({
            scope: this,
            callback: function(records ,operation, success) {
                Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
                 var json= Ext.encode(rec.raw);
                 var response=Ext.JSON.decode(json);
                 for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    form.add({
                        xtype: response.data[i].xtype,
                        fieldLabel: response.data[i].title,
                        name: response.data[i].name
                        });
                    }
                    //form.add(Ext.JSON.decode(json).data);
                    form.doLayout();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be done automatically if you insert it into any extjs component content :

```
var jsonValues =  "{
    "form": {
        "fields" : [
                {
                    "field":"textfield",
                    "name": "username"
                },
                { 
                    "field":"textfield",
                    "name": "password"
                },
            ]    
      }
}";

var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        id        : 'myPanel',
        items      : [jsonValues]
});

panel.show();
```